# How to communicate between C++ and JAVA via Memory-Mapped file without NMI?

Tags: java, c++

I have a C++ COMPILED code which takes two arguments: input file & output file. It's also not possible to pipe input and output. I want to call this program from a Java application. 
The only performance-improvement option which comes to mind, is to use memory-mapped files. The task is simple:

1. create two file (names)
2. call C++ compiled program and provide the file names (code manipulation is not possible, the code is too complicated)
3. read output file

How can I do it in Java?

Comment: Can you make the output file a named pipe?  This is simpler to read as it is written without polling the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by:

```
try {
  //Start the c++ program
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MyCppProgram.exe "+"intputFile "+"outputFile");
  // wait until the program finishes
  p.waitFor();
  // Done, process output file
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But this solution does not use a memory-mapped file.